# How can I force the usage of a repository?

Tags: 10.04, ppa, repository

I have added the following to my sources.list:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/experimental/ubuntu/ lucid main
```

Unfortunately, whenever I do a `sudo apt-get update`, the repository is ignored.  At least that's what I *think* `IGN` means in the following output.

Does anyone know how to force the use of a repository?

Here's the part where it says "ign":

`Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/experimental/ubuntu/ lucid/main Translation-en_US`

Comment: I've always thought that it means "Ignored because the repository information is up-to-date". You can check whether a repository is used by running `apt-cache policy`. Optionally add a package name of a package from the PPA.

Comment: @Lekensteyn, that's the main reason I asked. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Ign repo_link` means that the diff did not return any package updates so it was ignored.

You can force it by doing: `apt-get clean && apt-get update`
You can also optionally pin the repo: `vim /etc/apt/preferences.d/kubuntu-ppa-pin-900`

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-kubuntu-ppa,n=experimental
Pin-Priority: 900
```

900 puts it at the highest, anything less than 500 will make it less important than main repos.

Comment: Can you answer in general cases, How I can figure out Pin information o=something n=something? for example, `deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian precise contrib`