# Ubuntu 12.04 Will Not Use Cloud Archive Packages

Tags: 12.04, apt, cloud, openstack

I'm trying to get Keystone installed on my Ubuntu 12.04 from the Cloud Archive and it keeps installed the package from precise-updates.

Here's what `apt-cache madison keystone` reveals.

```
root@cloud:/etc/puppet# apt-cache madison keystone
  keystone | 1:2013.1.2-0ubuntu2~cloud0 | http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/grizzly/main amd64 Packages
  keystone | 2012.1.3+stable-20130423-f48dd0fc-0ubuntu1.1 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
  keystone | 2012.1.3+stable-20130423-f48dd0fc-0ubuntu1.1 | http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
  keystone | 2012.1-0ubuntu1 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
  keystone | 2012.1-0ubuntu1 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main Sources
  keystone | 2012.1.3+stable-20130423-f48dd0fc-0ubuntu1.1 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main Sources
  keystone | 2012.1.3+stable-20130423-f48dd0fc-0ubuntu1.1 | http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main Sources
  keystone | 1:2013.1.2-0ubuntu2~cloud0 | http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/grizzly/main Sources
```

But when I `apt-get install keystone` I get this version: `2012.1.3+stable-20130423-f48dd0fc-0ubuntu1.1` instead of the expected `1:2013.1.2-0ubuntu2~cloud0`. I suspect I must be doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what.

I'm trying to build up a Puppet manifest to automate this and need to figure out how to ensure the Apt installs the expected version when the Cloud Archive is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution thanks to this question: [Assign highest priority to my local repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135339/assign-highest-priority-to-my-local-repository)

Basically the standard precise-updates repos were getting assigned a priority of 990, which was well beyond the default priority of 10 that the cloud-archive received. So, a quick adjustment to pin the cloud archive with a priority of 1000 and the right package now installs.

In case anyone runs into this again, first check the output of `apt-cache policy keystone` to see what your version priorities are:

```
root@cloud:/etc/puppet# apt-cache policy keystone
keystone:
  Installed: 2012.1.3+stable-20130423-f48dd0fc-0ubuntu1.1
  Candidate: 2012.1.3+stable-20130423-f48dd0fc-0ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
     1:2013.1.2-0ubuntu2~cloud0 0
         10 http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/grizzly/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2012.1.3+stable-20130423-f48dd0fc-0ubuntu1.1 0
        990 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        990 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2012.1-0ubuntu1 0
        990 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

After adjusting my pins, the output now looks like this:

```
root@cloud:/etc/puppet# apt-cache policy keystone
keystone:
  Installed: 1:2013.1.2-0ubuntu2~cloud0
  Candidate: 1:2013.1.2-0ubuntu2~cloud0
  Version table:
 *** 1:2013.1.2-0ubuntu2~cloud0 0
       1000 http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/grizzly/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2012.1.3+stable-20130423-f48dd0fc-0ubuntu1.1 0
        990 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        990 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
     2012.1-0ubuntu1 0
        990 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Can I suggest that since this answer is about how you fixed it that you click the green checkmark next to this answer to mark it as officially solved?