# Is there a way to install a package from a particular repository using apt?

Tags: apt, ppa, aptitude

Sometimes a package I want from a PPA has the same name as a different package in another repository. Is there a way I can tell `apt` to download a package of `packageName` from a certain repo?

I'd prefer to just use `apt`, but I suppose `aptitude` or some other tool would work okay. The simpler the better.

Comment: check here http://askubuntu.com/questions/135339/assign-highest-priority-to-my-local-repository/153408#153408

Comment: One thing to ALWAYS check is if the PPA has a higher version number than the version in Ubuntu.  If it does, you won't need to worry about specifying it.  (Case in point, https://launchpad.net/~nginx/+archive/stable/ has newer version numbers for nginx than Ubuntu everywhere except in Trusty, so the PPA will by default always override the version in Ubuntu's repos for a given release (except Trusty at this time))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. [Pinning](https://askubuntu.com/a/153408/169736) -> this is more a permanent solution, you can remix it into something adhoc and it's detailed at the end.
2. Using aweso... err aptitude!

#### Using aptitude

Lets say the package is from some origin, lets call this `ppa.launchpad.net`. So, how to tell aptitude to install the package form that origin:

```
sudo aptitude install '?narrow(nameofthepackage, ?origin(ppa.launchpad.net))'
```

You can change `narrow` for `and`. Also, you can use other selectors like version string, etc.

A complete reference of all the features of aptitude here:

- http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s03s05.html

---

#### Using pinning.

This requires that you write the preference file before hand and you should add pretty options arguments:

You must write your pinning file:

```
Package: somepackage
Pin: origin ppa.launchpad.net
Pin-Priority: 1000
```

Now with apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install -o Dir::Etc::Preferences=/path/to/pinningFile somepackage
```

Done.

Comment: `/path/to/file` goes... where? The pinning file?

Comment: Do make a note that if the version number in the PPA is higher than the package version number in Ubuntu's repos, `dpkg` will prefer the higher package version number, whether you're pinning or not.  (Per my comment above on the question, where there's an example of this explained)

Comment: @ThomasW. I'm pinning a specific repository (ie, Install always from here and ignore everything else), and apt will do the impossible to meets my demands. ;)

Comment: True, however, I just wanted to make that known, that for older releases like Precise, that isn't always going to be a problem :)